# How to convert int to ID?

Tags: java, android

I have 9 buttons (button1 ... button 9) and I generate random numbers (1-9).

I want to random change BG color for button who has the same number as the random number. = rand.Num = 6 -> button6 has BG red. Thx <3

Comment: Button Id is integer...

Comment: sorry :D i named them ID: 1-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:tag` in your Button view. In your view, set the attribute tag:

```
<Button
   android:id="button_1"
   android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:tag="1"/>
```

Then you can use **[findViewByTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object))**:

```
int[] colors = {
        ...
        Color.RED, // the 6th color.
        ...
};

Random rand = new Random();
int tag = rand.nextInt((9 - 1) + 1) + 1;

Button button = (Button) findViewByTag(String.valueOf(tag));
button.setBackgroundColor(colors[tag - 1]); // -1 because array start from 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you need,

```
    int[] buttons = {
            R.id.button1,
            R.id.button2,
            R.id.button3,
            R.id.button4,
            R.id.button5,
            R.id.button6,
            R.id.button7,
            R.id.button8,
            R.id.button9
    };
    int[] bgColors = {
            Color.MAGENTA,
            Color.BLACK,
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.CYAN,
            Color.RED,
            Color.YELLOW,
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.GRAY,
            Color.DKGRAY
    };
    for (int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int id = rand.nextInt((9 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(buttons[i]);
        button.setText("ID"+String.valueOf(id));
        button.setBackgroundColor(bgColors[id-1]);
    }
```